# sorting images in correct order

Tags: python, image, list, sorting

I am trying to pick all the images from a folder with an especific name.

The images have the following names:

```
plotChannel1.png, plotChannel2.png, plotChannel3.png, plotChannel4.png, plotChannel5.png, plotChannel6.png, plotChannel7.png, plotChannel8.png, plotChannel9.png, plotChannel10.png, plotChannel12.png, plotChannel13.png, plotChannel14.png, plotChannel5.png, plotChannel6.png
```

To pick the images I am using:

```
dataImage = sort([f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('.png') and 'Channel' in f])
```

However the result is not as expected, since python is not sorting them in the correct order. It uses the following order:

```
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

How can I force python to sort the images in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) accepts an additional `key` function parameter. Pass a function that convert the filename into number, so that `sorted` sort according to the number, instead of sort it lexicographically.

```
dataImage = sorted(
    [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('.png') and 'Channel' in f]
    key=lambda filename: int(filter(str.isdigit, filename))
)
```